# MultiValueDictKeyError while submitting django formset

Tags: python, django

i'm working on a Django app where I am trying to submit a form and a formset in one go.

Getting the formset to render works flawlessly, but submitting it with a POST generates an error... Once i comment out generating the formset from POST data, all works fine, and the form submits without errors

The thing is, the error I get is not very descriptive:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /questions/question/add
'0'
```

these are my view methods:

```
def get(self, request, question_id=-1):
    initial_data = {
        'categories': 1,
        'subcategories': 2,
        'questionEditor': "Test initial",
        'isOpenQuestion': True,
        'isMultiChoice': False,
    }

    category = request.session['category'] if 'category' in request.session else 0
    initial_data['categories'] = category

    formset_initial_data = list()
    if question_id > 0:
        question = Question.objects.get(id=question_id)
        initial_data = {
            'categories': question.subcategories.category.id,
            'subcategories': question.subcategories.id,
            'questionEditor': question.description,
            'isOpenQuestion': question.isOpenQuestion,
            'isMultiChoice': question.isMultiChoice,
        }

        for index, answer in enumerate(question.answer_set.all()):
            print answer.description
            formset_initial_data.append({
                'formulaAnswerEditor': answer.description,
                'answerInputBox': answer.isCorrect,
            })

    question_edit_formset = formset_factory(forms.QuestionEditAnswerForm, extra=(3 if len(formset_initial_data) == 0 else 0))
    formset = question_edit_formset(initial=formset_initial_data)

    form = forms.QuestionEditForm(data=initial_data)
    data = {
        'form': form,
        'formset': formset,
    }
    return render(request, "questionEdit.html", dictionary=data)


def post(self, request, question_id=-1):
    print request.POST
    form = forms.QuestionEditForm(data=request.POST)
    question_answers_formset = formset_factory(forms.QuestionEditAnswerForm, extra=0)
    formset = question_answers_formset(initial=request.POST)

    print form, formset
```

the form class

```
class QuestionEditAnswerForm(forms.Form):
    id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    answerInputBox = forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={
        'class': 'answer-input-type',
        'type': 'radio',
    }))

    formulaAnswerEditor = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
        'class': "answer-text-area-style answer-cke-remove-bottom-toolbar cke-placeholder"}))
```

template:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}

{% for single_answer in formset %}

    {{ single_answer.id }}
    <div class="margin-answer">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                {{ single_answer.answerInputBox }}
            </span>
            {{ single_answer.formulaAnswerEditor }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

new forms to the formset are added using JS, but even if I don't add any new form, the error persists...

I have tried following answers to similar questions, but so far with no luck

If anyone knows how to figure this out, I'd be grateful :)

EDIT: full traceback (i'm relatively new to Django and Python, so that doesn't say too much to me :))

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/questions/question/add

Django Version: 1.9.6
Python Version: 2.7.11
Installed Applications:
['suit',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'MainPage',
 'News',
 'Registration',
 'StaticSites',
 'UserDetails',
 'Questions',
 'Competitions']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/path/to/env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/path/to/env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/path/to/env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/path/to/env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/path/to/env/ekonkurs/Questions/views.py" in post
  221.         print form, formset

File "/path/to/env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in <lambda>
  842.         klass.__str__ = lambda self: self.__unicode__().encode('utf-8')

File "/path/to/env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/html.py" in <lambda>
  381.         klass.__unicode__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_unicode(self))

File "/path/to/env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in __str__
  70.         return self.as_table()

File "/path/to/env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in as_table
  413.         forms = ' '.join(form.as_table() for form in self)

File "/path/to/env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in __iter__
  74.         return iter(self.forms)

File "/path/to/env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  33.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/path/to/env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in forms
  144.                  for i in range(self.total_form_count())]

File "/path/to/env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in _construct_form
  170.                 defaults['initial'] = self.initial[i]

File "/path/to/env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  85.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /questions/question/add
Exception Value: '0'
```

Comment: Error messages alone tend to not be very descriptive, but complete tracebacks are...

Comment: I've added error traceback to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `post` method: you're passing the data to the formset as the `initial` parameter, rather than `data` as you do with the form.

(Note that you seem to be making the opposite mistake in the `get` method; you're passing initial data to the form as `data`, rather than `initial`.)

Comment: Thanks, that works just fine :) I haven't noticed that and didn't recognize the significance :)